# Body parsers behaving weirdly

Tags: node.js, rest, express, middleware, body-parser

I am trying to develop an app with few APIs, the issue I am facing here is when I use

```
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

as my middleware, it doesnt intake the requests i send through postman (all the request sent through postman goes with empty body idk why. And it takes all the requests sent via html form.

On the other hand, if I use

```
app.use(express.json({extended: false}))
```

as my middleware to parse json objects, it takes all the requests from postman but doesnt take requests from my browser form. Can anyone explain whats happening here?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same body format in postman and in HTML? Can you share the examples?

Comment: @Abhineet: Both statements are working as expected. I don't see any issue with these. Is it possible to share the example data you're using in Postman and with type e.g. form-data, raw, JSON, etc.

Comment: I got the issue, I thought that 1 of them should be sufficient to run on both the platform but I require both as the answer suggests. I still will have to read the doc to know why that is the case. @AnastasiiaSolop Yes I am using same body format : here are the links to snapshot of actual requests=> Postman: http://prntscr.com/uuxf30 HTML form:http://prntscr.com/uuxftj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for express to be able to parse both JSON request payloads and simple form-data requests, you simply need to setup **both** of the mentioned middlewares (note that `express.json()` does not have an extended option):

```
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
 app.use(express.json());
```

See the docs for more information:

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json
https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded